# Python 101 and Math Logic - Listing square root numbers less than n

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counter, square-root

I'm stuck on a [Python 101 type problem involving loops](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/7c-loops/). Here are the directions:

The square numbers are the integers of the form K × K, e.g. 9 is a square number since 3 × 3 = 9. Write a program that reads an integer n from input and outputs all the positive square numbers less than n, one per line in increasing order. For example, if the input is 16, then the correct output would be

```
1
4
9
```

This is what I have so far but it sort of works but runs on forever. My code never reaches the if statement so it breaks(stops) before it gets to 17.

Suppose n = 17.

```
n=int(input())
counter = 1
while counter * counter < n:
   for counter in range(1,n):
      a = counter*counter
      print(a)
   if a < n:
      break
```

Results:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Comment: What is `n` in that particular loop?

Comment: 17. I think I mentioned it. "Suppose n = 17."

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that.

Comment: Here's a hint: you only need one loop but here you have two. Here's another: `a` ends up being `counter*counter`. why would you only break if `a < n`, that is, if `counter*counter < n`? wouldn't you want to break if `counter*counter > n`?

Comment: I think it might be because you're breaking out of the for loop, but you are not altering `counter` so the while loop will continuously run

Comment: Claudiu, wouldn't the code not even get there because if counter*counter > n and you assign counter=1, you would never get to counter*counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a correction of your code.

```
n=int(input())
counter = 1
for counter in range(1,n):
    a = counter*counter
    if a >= n:
        break
    print(a)
```

There were three things wrong with your code. First, the condition you want to break on is `a >= n` not `a < n`. Second, that condition needs to be tested before you print the number. Thus the `if` statement needs to be inside the `for` loop and before your `print`, statement. Third, the outer `while` loop is not really necessary :) Though you can add it, but a simple inner `for` loop will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`if a < n:` will never succeed unless `n = 2`; because inside the loop `a` is becoming `(n-1)*(n-1)` which is greater than `n` for `n > 2`; that's why the infinite loop. Try this:

```
>>> counter = 1
>>> n = 16 # int(input())
>>> r = counter**2
>>> while r<n:
    print r
    counter += 1
    r = counter**2


1
4
9
```

Or just modify yours one by removing the outer loop, and placing the conditional *inside* the for loop like:

```
for counter in range(1,n):
      a = counter*counter
      if a >= n:break
      print(a)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't correct the direction I was headed. Could you correct my code? It's very close. It just loops past n.

Comment: Great answer, but I think Shashank's answer was a little more thorough and used the code direction I was headed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code loops might be the case in you semantics error try this out light on the memory and simple

def number(n):

```
for i in range(0,n):
    w=i*i
    if w>n-1:
        break

    print(w)
```

number(144)

Answer (score 0):

#### What about

```
    n= int(input())
    counter= 1
    while counter * counter < n:
        print( counter * counter )
        counter+= 1
```

#### ?

Comment: That creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You've got three issues here, but, as you can tell, you're on the right track.

1. First off, you're using two loops when you only need to be using one, and I think it's because you're a little unclear as to how the `while` loop works. The `while` loop checks that the condition is true before each time it runs. If the condition becomes false while going through the loop, the loop will still finish - it just won't start another. For example:

   ```
   n = 17
   while n < 18:
       n += 1
       print n
       n += 1
       print n
   ```

   prints:

   ```
   18
   19
   ```

   In your case, each iteration through the `while` loop creates a `for` loop. In order for a single iteration through the `while` to take place, your computer has to go through for every number from `1` to `n`, meaning that it'll print out all those extra numbers before your while loop even has a second chance to do its check. The easiest way to fix this is to remove the `while` loop and structure your code a little differently. As I'll show you in a few lines, you don't really need it.
2. When you say `if a < n:`, you've got your sign backwards and you need an equals sign. The problem asks that you give all values *less* than `n`, but, without the `=`, the program won't stop until it's *greater* than `n`. It should be `if a >= n:`.
3. Finally, the order of the operations isn't what you want it to be. You'd like it to check that `a` is less than `n` before printing, but you print before you do that check. If you switch them around, you'll get something like this:

   ```
   n=int(input())
   for counter in range(1,n):
       a = counter*counter
       if a >= n:
           break
       print(a)
   ```

   which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Turtle man was perfect but for me. I needed to be able to get all the way to 100  so if you need to get past 81 do this

```py
n = int(input())

counter = 1

for counter in range(1,n + 1):
    
    a = counter*counter
    
    if a > n:
        
break
    
print(a)
```